# Heat Equation Boundary Value Problem - alternative expressions for solution

Tags: brownian-motion, heat-equation

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion, with with density function $f(t,x)dx = P(B_t \in dx)$. Then $f$ solves the heat equation $\partial_t = \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx}f(t,x)$. Let for a fixed $u > 0$, $\bar{B}_t = \sup_{s \leq t}B_s$, and let  $$q(t,x)dx = P( \bar{B}_t > u, B_t \in dx).$$
Then $q$ still solves the heat equation with initial condition $q(0,x) = 0$ for $x < u$ and boundary condition $q(t,u) = p(t,u)$, $t \geq 0$. Using the classical theory of heat equation, one can write down an explicit expression for $q$:
$$
q(t,x) = \int_0^t f(s,u) \partial_x f(t-s,x-u)ds. \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Show that $q$ can also be written as
$$
\begin{align}
q(t,x) &= \int_0^t f(t-s,x-u) \partial_u f(s,u)ds \label{2}\tag{2} \\
&= \int_0^t f(t-s,x-u) \frac{u}{s}f(s,u) ds. \label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
I can think of a heuristic probabilistic argument involving path reversal of Brownian motion. Is there an analytic way to go from expression \eqref{1} to \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}?

I can see that the expression \eqref{2}/\eqref{3} satisfies the heat equation, but haven't been able to show that it satisfies the boundary condition. That may be sufficient.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thanks for the edit  :-)